Is every Fermat number that is not equal to $3$ a Connell Number?
A Fermat number is a number of the form $2^{2^{k}}+1.$ A Fermat number which is also a prime number is called a Fermat prime. Only five Fermat primes are known: $3,5,17,257,$ and $65537,$ and it is widely believed they are the only ones. It can be shown that if $2^{t}+1$ is a prime number then $t$ is necessarily a power of $2.$ Writing in 1959 to the journal American Mathematical Monthly Ian Connell challenged readers to find a closed form to an unusual sequence. The sequence, which now bears his name, is made as follows: begin by writing the first odd number, $1$, then write the next two even numbers after $1$: $2, 4$ and then write the next three odd numbers after $4$: $5, 7, 9$ and then write the next four even numbers after $9$: $10, 12, 14, 16$, and so on. The first few terms are $1, 2, 4, 5, 7, 9, 10, 12, 14, 16, 17,\ldots$ A solution to Connell’s challenge appeared
in the same journal in 1960, where it was shown the $n$-th term of the Connell sequence, $a_{n}$, has the closed form $2n − \lfloor1/2(1 + \sqrt{8n − 7})\rfloor$. It is known that $\lim_{n \to\infty}a_{n}n^{-1}=2.$ I say that a number is a Connell number if it belongs to the Connell sequence.

Question: Is every Fermat number that is not equal to $3$ a Connell Number?

Here is a working example:
$$
F_{2}=2\cdot 11-\left\lfloor\frac{1+\sqrt{8\cdot 11-7}}{2}\right\rfloor=22-\left\lfloor\frac{1+\sqrt{81}}{2}\right\rfloor=22-\left\lfloor\frac{10}{2}\right\rfloor=22-5=17.
$$
Of course $11=22/2=(5+17)/2.$ The observation here is that the position $n$ of $F_{k}$ in the Connell sequence is determined by $({F_{k-1}+F_{k}})/2.$ For example we expect $17$ to be in the $11-$th position of the Connell number sequence - and it is. I feel like I am robbing Peter to pay Paul, but is a solution that works.

Why do you believe this? How far have you searched?

I have searched, or tried rather, the numbers $5,17,$ and $257.$

It seems that $$g(n):=2^{2^n-1}+2^{2^{n-1}-1}+1$$
satisfies $$a_{g(n)}=2^{2^n}+1=F_n$$
where $a_n$ is the above sequence and $F_n$ the $n$ th Fermat number.
This works for $1\le n\le 20$ (checked with PARI/GP)
Maybe someone can prove this in general.

Peter - thank you for your contribution. It appears the answer may be more approachable than we thought. Observe: $2^{2^k}$ is a square. Evidently a Connell number always comes after a square number. Given that Fermat numbers are one more than a square it follows that Fermat numbers are Connell numbers. The exception here is $3$. So really to answer our question we need to show that,

A Connell number always proceeds a square number.

But as pointed out by @lulu this is true.
Note this approach does not actually provide us with an explanation as to why $({F_{k-1}+F_{k}})/2$ is a solution.

Not following.  $7$ is a Connell number and it does not precede a square, nor is it preceded by a square.

Or was your claim meant to read "$n^2+1$ is  a Connell number for any $n\in \mathbb N$"?  Cursory inspection seems to show that both $n^2$ and $n^2+1$ belong to the sequence.

Careful , I wrote a Connell number proceeds a square, not that all Connell numbers proceed a square. So for example the Connell numbers proceeding, $4, 9, 16, 25,$ and $36$ are $5,10,17,26,$ and $37$. The $7$ would be an example of a Connell number that does not proceed a square. And your inspection is true, every square is a Connell number. This answers the question of the post.

Not sure what you mean by "proceed".  I assumed you meant to write "precede" but that claim is clearly false.  I am not aware of any context in which "proceed" means "follow".  In any case, the quantifiers in your claim are very unclear.

As I say, I believe you meant to write:  "$n\in \mathbb N\implies n^2+1$ is a Connell number".  As I say, just looking at the sequence up to $a_{1000}$ it seems that both $n^2,n^2+1$ are always in the sequence.

@lulu if you would consider making your comment into an answer, I would accept it as an answer.

An answer?  But I have no idea if the claim is true or not.  As I say, I just visually scanned the list of the first $1000$ terms of the sequence and it seems to hold.  I'd want to check it a whole lot further out before stating it as a conjecture.  Again, I have no proof of the claim, just a quick visual check (which, of course, is error prone).

At least half of my weak conjecture is true:  $a_{T_n}=n^2$ where $T_n=\frac {n(n+1)}2$ is the $n^{th}$ triangular number.  See this.  Perhaps the other half can be shown by similar means (trusting that it is true).  The hope would, of course, be that $a_{T_n+1}=n^2+1$.

To summarize the discussion in the comments:
The claim in the literature is that $n\in \mathbb N$ implies that both $n^2,n^2+1$ are Connell numbers.
As the Fermat numbers $>3$  are all of the form $n^2+1$, that would suffice to settle the question at hand.
More specifically, if $a[k]$ denotes the $k^{th}$ Connell number, then this reference claims that $$a[T_n]=a\left[ \frac {n(n+1)}2\right]=n^2$$
where, as usual, $T_n$ denotes the $n^{th}$ triangular number.
And the relevant OEIS page, A001614 asserts that $a[k]=n^2$ implies that $a[k+1]=n^2+1$.
To be sure, neither site includes enough detail to constitute a proof, but at least it is a start.
As my post contains little content beyond links, I'll post this as a community wiki.  If someone could supply proper proofs, that would be a better answer.
